# How can I make a SQL query that returns null if there is no record or return the value if there is?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to do a query on three different tables.

1. The variable table

   - The variable table carries information about what `"area"`, `"rounds"` and 
     `"days"` the variable belongs to. The variable table also holds a pk column.
     The pk is used to determine which variable a record belongs to.
2. The area table

   - The area table carries information about the `"name"` of the area as well as
     the `"role"` the area belongs to. A user is assigned a role and then has 
     access to specific areas.
3. The record table

   - The record table carries information about the record that was entered. It
     contains the `"value"`, `"alarmed"`, and `"alarmType"` columns. You can search
     for a record based on the variable, round and day.

I am trying to query all of the variables in a certain round and day for a user.
I want to display all the variables whether or not there is a record found. Currently I have a query that only returns the variables that have records, but not the ones that don't.

If there is no record then the`value, alarmed, and alarmType` column should be null.

This is the query that I have so far constructed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT variable.name, area.name AS "areaName", variable.pk, CAST(record.value AS TEXT) AS "value", record.alarmed, record.alarmType 
FROM variable, area, record 
WHERE variable.round LIKE '%,1,%' 
  AND variable.day LIKE '%,3,%' 
  AND variable.readOnly = 0 
  AND variable.area IN (SELECT pk 
                        FROM area 
                        WHERE role = (SELECT role 
                                      FROM user 
                                      WHERE userName LIKE 'Leo')) 
  AND variable.area = area.pk 
  AND record.value = (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT() < 1 THEN NULL 
                             ELSE CAST(value AS TEXT) END 
                      FROM record 
                      WHERE round = 1 
                        AND day = "11-14-2018" 
                        AND variable = variable.pk) 
ORDER BY variable.area, variable.position ASC;
```

Currently it returns something like this:

[image: What this query returns]

There are a lot more variables and I want to know how to display them even if there are no records.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a JOIN type of query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do. The key is using joins (specifically OUTER joins) instead of trying to mash all the tables together and then find similarities.  There are also `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `INNER` flavors (read more about these [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/t-sql-join-types) and [here](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-outer-joins/)), depending on what you consider the "complete" or "master" data set - the starting point of your query.

Here's how I understand your relationships (let me know if I have this wrong):

```
record.variable --> variable.pk
variable.area --> area.pk
area.role --> user.role
```

In your case, you stated that you need all records from the `variable` table, so I would start with this:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM variable v;
```

Then, you might find all the AREA records related to a particular USER. Use an `INNER` join to find only records that exist on BOTH sides of the join:

```
SELECT a.*, u.*
FROM area a
INNER JOIN user u         -- Define the table to join
   ON a.role = u.role     -- Which columns contain keys to match on
WHERE u.userName = 'Leo';
```

The WHERE filter applies to the `user` table, but because we are ONLY asking for records from the `area` table that have a match with user, then that limits the results from the `area` table.

The next step is to join these two extracts together using another `INNER` join, again, to find the intersection - matches that exist on BOTH sides of the join(s):

```
SELECT v.*, a.*, u.*
FROM variable v           -- New starting point
INNER JOIN area a
   ON a.pk = v.area
INNER JOIN user u
   ON a.role = u.role
WHERE u.userName = 'Leo';
```

Now, we find all the records for a certain day by adding `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT v.*, a.*, u.*
FROM variable v
INNER JOIN area a
   ON a.pk = v.area
INNER JOIN user u
   ON a.role = u.role
WHERE u.userName = 'Leo'
AND v.round = 1           -- Add filters for "round"
AND v.day = '11-14-2018'; -- and "day" columns
```

Next, we use a `LEFT` join to give us all the records from the table on the "left" plus any matches we find on the "right" side (the "record" table) or NULL if no match is made:

```
SELECT v.name
   ,a.name as "areaName"
   ,CAST(r.value as TEXT) as "value"
   ,r.alarmed
   ,r.alarmType
FROM variable v
INNER JOIN area a
   ON v.area = a.pk
INNER JOIN user u
   ON a.role = u.role
LEFT JOIN record r        -- LEFT is important here
   ON v.pk = r.variable
WHERE u.userName = 'Leo'
AND v.round = 1
AND v.day = '11-14-2018'
ORDER BY v.area, v.position;
```

The result from `INNER` joins (`variable` + `area` + `user`) becomes the "left" side of this join, and the `record` becomes the "right" side. Using the `LEFT` join declares that we want ALL records from the left, whether they have a match on the right or not.

I don't have a dataset to test this with, so please excuse any errors I've made.

Hopefully, this illustrates how joins would be used to both eliminate rows and add data (columns) the result, without having to make individual queries or resort to sub-queries (using `IN` or `EXISTS`).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input epluribusunix. I am getting the same results as the query above. I know this can be done as an iteration once we found the variable pk's. I was thinking there are 154 variables. Instead of making 154 queries, we could get all the results in one. For some rounds there may be around 400 variables. What is practical?

Comment: @Chris, I would definitely try to stay away from making multiple queries.  That's a LOT of overhead for something that should be relatively straightforward.  I have edited my answer, so please review the data model at the top and let me know what I've missed.

Comment: What do you mean `154` variable? is it `154` table with same name variable? And this answer are good approach rather you use subqery..

Comment: Hello, there are 154 variables in this specific round. Variables can have at most one record per round on a specific date. I want to display all the variables with their record. If there is no account of a record I want it to be null.